# Add-on to place a pixel grid on top of browser window for IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Is there a way to put a pixel grid on top of Internet Explorer?

Something along the lines of the GridFox add on for FireFox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly what I was looking for but I ended up using this - http://gridulator.com/ and then adding it as a background image to the body tag in css